# Make curved text on coord_polar() upright

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

suppose I have this dataset

```
data3 <- data.frame(
    id = c(1:10),
    marker = paste("Marker", seq(1, 10, 1)),
    value = paste(rep(c(0,1), times = 2, length.out = 10))
    ) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number(), angle = 90 - 360 * (id - 0.5) / n())
```

I want to make a chart like this:
[[image: Image taken from Royam et al, 2019][1]]
Image taken from [Royam et al, 2019](https://dx.doi.org/10.3390%2Fcancers11070900)

I have tried using coord_polar() with codes as follow:

```
ggplot(data = data3, aes(x = factor(id), y = 2, fill = factor(value), label = marker)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
    geom_text(hjust = 1.5, angle = data3$angle) +
    coord_polar() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c('green', 'red'), 0.3), breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c('Upregulated', 'Downregulated')) +
    guides(fill = 'none') +
    theme(
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), 
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank()
        )
```

Which returns this figure:
[image]

How can I make the labels kept upright? Additionally, am I going to the right direction in creating the sample plot? Is there any other command in ggplot2 which may create such a figure?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I'm sure you _can_ do this in `ggplot`, but for more sophisticated text layouts in similar diagrams I think `circlize` is an excellent tool with excellent documentation. See e.g. [the text section](https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/graphics.html#text)

Comment: @Henrik `circlize` seems to provide more functions with circular plots than ggplot. Thank you very much for the suggestion, will try to familiarize myself with the package.